# pgbench : too many client connections for select()

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

[image]
I was working on benchmark testing for pg10 and pg14.

I did the testing for 100 clients with 12 threads in pg14 I was getting following error,

"pgbench:too many client connections for select()" (screen shot attached)

The same was working fine in pg10, can anybody help me with this issue.

Below is the command used to test,

.\pgbench.exe -d -r -h localhost -U postgres -p 5434 -T 600 -c 100 -j 12 pgbench

Comment: Please do not post text info as an image.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: At any rate, the error message is new in [commit 60e612b6029](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=60e612b602999e670f2d57a01e52799eaa903ca9).

Comment: That looks like PowerShell, so probably Windows. Windows has a particularly low limit on the number of connections per thread, so increasing `-j` or reducing `-c` may avoid the error.